# Can users of the self service portal delete attachments that were submitted by them?

Tags: customer-portal, portal, enterprise

Users (and super users) of the Self Service Portal can submit and view attachments but can't delete.

How do I Add a delete attachment or remove attachment button to the "attachments list in the  "view cases" page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems at first, but I couldn't quite test your scenario as Self-Service is no longer available :-(

- Is the Case Contact correctly assigned to the associated contact/user record pair?
- What's the Profile of your Self Service user?
- Can you show us your High-Volume Portal User Sharing Settings?

[image: delete attachment]

Comment: Hi it seems that we do not have the same salesforce version or license 
I can't change the user  Profile of the Self Service user. I guess we are using the default 
I do not have High-Volume Portal User Sharing Settings. All I have a SELF SERVICE PORTAL settings.
Do you know if this is available for the Enterprise Edition?

Comment: I think Self-Service Portal does not appear at all in new orgs. Enterprise orgs will get Customer Portal and the High-Volume Portal User profiles.